# Spring boot 1.4 with spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings to true generates Id randomly not in sequence

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 1.4 with Hibernate 5, for `TableGenerator` with initial value I have changed `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings` to `true` but the generated ID's(auto increment) are not in sequance then are in increasing order with some random gaps. I found that these ID's are in sequence of update operation across the tables. I should I achieve the sequential ID generation for particular table.

I have following configuration for Sequence Generator

```
@Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @TableGenerator(name = "id_generator", table = "id_gen", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_val",initialValue=10001,allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "id_generator")
    private Long id;
```

Generation ID scenario

Table1(ID) 1 2 4 5

Table2(ID) 3 6

With hibernate_sequence table with multiple values as same value
hibernate_sequence(next_val) 7 7 7 7

Comment: Are you using the same generator (`@TableGenerator(name = "id_generator", table = "id_gen"...`) for several entities ? if it is the case, it is expected that the generated ids will be split among several tables. Also keep in mind that errors triggering rollback of tx do not give back generated ids of insert that are later rolled back. So you can't expect rows to not have gaps in id attribution.

Comment: @Thierry no i am using id_generator for that entity only..and also no errors occured during execution